# Does Jn 3:8 have a larger interpretation with reference to Gifts of Holy Spirit?

Tags: exegesis, trinity, gospel-of-john, spiritual-gifts, spirit

In Jn 3:8, we see Jesus equating those born of the Holy Spirit to the wind which blows where it likes. No one knows where the wind comes from and where it goes to. Jesus was referring to the place of origin of the wind and it's final destination , and not just the directions ( east/west etc..) it blows from and goes to. We know that the Holy Spirit comes from the Father. Origin of the people born of the Spirit is also known , whereas their destination is not predictable. So, was Jesus actually referring to the Gifts of the Spirit, say Gift of the Gab, Gift of Healing etc...those born of the Spirit may receive ? No one can foresee when the Gifts are given and taken back.  My question therefore is: Is  there a  larger interpretation of John 3:8 with reference to Gifts of the Holy Spirit ? Inputs from Trinitarians are solicited.